# Reset changes on angular reactive form

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I developped a reactive form in angular :

Select dropdown List  ===>  [id] = 1, 2, 3....etc

input text            ===>  name : .....

input text            ===>  adress : .....

input text            ===>  Description : .....

I fill the the form by calling a http get service based on selected id in both ngOnInit and (change) handler on select dropdown List

I have two buttons : "validate" and "cancel" Modifications

User can modify inputs data values and save modifications on validate button click.

What is the the best way to cancel modifications done by the user?

Comment: sending the same request again would be easy :p

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! In addition to the above option, if you are using reactive forms you should still have a copy of the original object. Just reset the values from the object you have.

Comment: *"best"* how? What is and what's the problem with your current implementation?

Comment: I would use a function to load all values on the initial start of the page, and add a button that calls that function again to 'reset' the form

Comment: I didtn wanted to recall the service after each cancel, it is not practical, 
especially in the real case I have a big forum and that takes a little time to be filled, so from what I understood , when calling the service I will save the data in an object !

Comment: When you cancel you want to get previous data?

Comment: So if we edit out the word "best" way, does this become a valid question that no longer needs to be on hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Reactive forms, your object values are not bound to the form so any changes the user makes do *not* modify the original object.

You can copy the values from your existing object back over the form values using code like this:

```
// Update the data on the form
this.productForm.patchValue({
  productName: this.product.productName,
  productCode: this.product.productCode,
  starRating: this.product.starRating,
  description: this.product.description
});
```

**Update**

I assume your current process is this:

1) In the ngOnInit, retrieve your data and store it in a property, such as `product` shown in the code above.

2) Then you populate the form using code similar to the above.

When the user makes changes, the changes are *not* made to the original property (`product` in this example). Rather they are made to the form model defined with the FormGroup.

So all you need to do is repeat the code from step 2 to cancel any changes and return the form to its state as before the user made any updates.

Does that make sense?

Comment: I want to cancel changes after modifications by user ! I dont understund what do you mean ? can you give me an example please ? I copy the original object when I subscribe on service ?

Comment: If you want to do a **SMALL** example of what you are trying to accomplish on stackblitz.com, we can provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a reset method on form controls in angular:

```
reset(value?: any, options?: {
    onlySelf?: boolean;
    emitEvent?: boolean;
}): void;
```

Example

```
class Component {
  form: FormGroup;

  resetForm() {
    this.form.reset();
  }
}
```